# The function I wrote to fetch data in the database returns empty. There is data in the database. In flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, future, sqflite

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Notlar(dirty, state: _NotlarState#20db1):
The method 'notListesiniGetir' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: notListesiniGetir()

Photo-3 code here:

```
[Future<int> kategoriSil(int kategoriID) async {
    var db= await _getDatabase();
    var sonuc= await db.delete("kategori",  where: 'kategoriID= ?', whereArgs: \[kategoriID\]);
    return sonuc;
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> notlariGetir() async {
    var db = await _getDatabase();
    var sonuc= await db.rawQuery('select * from "not" inner join kategori on kategori.kategorID = "not".kategoriID;');
    return sonuc;
  }
  Future<List<Not>> notListesiniGetir() async{
    var notlarMapListesi = await notlariGetir();
    var notListesi = List<Not>();
    for(Map map in notlarMapListesi){
      notListesi.add(Not.fromMap(map));

    }
    return notListesi;

  }][1]
```

error code:======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Notlar(dirty, state: _NotlarState#20db1):
The method 'notListesiniGetir' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: notListesiniGetir()

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Notlar file:///C:/Flutter%20calismalari/not_sepeti/lib/main.dart:63:27
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _NotlarState.build (package:not_sepeti/main.dart:166:30)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4802:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4685:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4857:11)
...

[enter image description hereBwg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9pcS.png)

Comment: My guess is that you're not waiting for the future to complete somewhere.

Comment: I am more novice in this field. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your code but in your screenshot (that you should add to your question as a code snippet).

You have to await the condition `snapshot.hasData`

Change from

```dart
If (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
```

To

```dart
If (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData)
```

Also

```dart
var notListesi = List<Not>()
List<Not> notListesi = <Not>[ ]; // better
```

And more importantly remove `DatabaseHelper` in your init state:

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaSeHelper();
```

To

```
databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
```

it will be working.

Comment: Can you print snapshot.data and comment the output?

Comment: Also Print databaseHelper at the beginning of your buildcontext , that may be the reason.

Comment: lib/main.dart:161:73: Error: A value of type 'List<Not>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Not' is from 'package:not_sepeti/models/notlar.dart' ('lib/models/notlar.dart').
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.data) {

Comment: Remove DatabaseHelper keyword in your initState

Comment: It is ```snapshot.hasData``` and not ```snapshot.data```

Comment: The second Solution tried your suggestion worked. You are great person. Thank you. I'm a little bad at the programming stage. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can select it as answer and upvote, glad to help you! To improve read online tutorials and documentation

Comment: I hope I got the grading right. Can you find the right source for Flutter